# How to test an AlertDialog in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, button, click, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to test an `AlertDialog` with `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`.

Here is the original code :

```
    this.setmBtAppelerFixe(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InterventionImmobiliereDetailsActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Appel");
            dialog.setMessage("Appeler le contact ?");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    InterventionImmobiliereDetailsActivity.this.lancerIntentAppel(mIntervention.getTelContact());
                }
            });

            mAdAppelerFixe = dialog.create();
            mAdAppelerFixe.show();
        }
    });
```

Now I can't manage to click on the Positive Button. This code doesn't seem to work :

```
    mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            assertTrue(mLLAppelerFixe.performClick());

            AlertDialog mDialog = mActivity.getAdAppelerFixe();
            assertTrue(mDialog.isShowing());

            Button okButton = mDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

            assertTrue(okButton.performClick());
            assertTrue(mActivity.isNumeroValide());
        }
    });
```

First I perform a click on my layout to open the `AlertDialog`.
Then I get the `OK_BUTTON` and I perform a click on it. It should set the `numeroValide` boolean at true.
But nothing.

How can I simply test an `AlertDialog` with buttons ?

Answer (score 5):

This is working perfectly in my nexus 4 device:

```
@MediumTest
public void testStartMyActivity() {
    monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MyActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    TouchUtils.clickView(this, startMyActivityButton);

    MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) monitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(2000);
    assertNotNull("MyActivity activity not started, activity is null", myActivity);

    AlertDialog dialog = myActivity.getLastDialog(); // I create getLastDialog method in MyActivity class. Its return last created AlertDialog
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        try {
            performClick(dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    myActivity.finish();
    getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(monitor);
}

private void performClick(final Button button) throws Throwable {
    runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.performClick();
        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
}
```

**Here example testing AlertDialog**(from android google source):
[AlertDialogTest.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/1a4b0ea/tests/tests/app/src/android/app/cts/AlertDialogTest.java)

Answer (score 4):

In your original activity you can create a simple method to return the instance of last AlertDialog.

```
public AlertDialog getDialog(){
    return alertDialog;
}
```

In the test activity you can access the alert dialog and click the button using the following code.

```
ActivityMonitor monitor =  getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MyActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) monitor.waitForActivity();
getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();    

// access the alert dialog using the getDialog() method created in the activity
AlertDialog dialog = myActivity.getDialog();

// access the button
Button okBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
TouchUtils.clickView(this, okBtn);
getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(monitor);
```

Answer (score 2):

To click AlertDialog buttons use Espresso

to click positive button

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button1)).perform(click());
```

and to click negative button

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.button2)).perform(click());
```

for more info visit [Espresso Examples Dialog Tests](https://github.com/vgrec/EspressoExamples/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/vgrec/espressoexamples/DialogTests.java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Espresso for now with code

```
onView(withText("South China Sea"))
  .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
  .perform(click());
```

See [EspressoSamples](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples)